# How to prevent people to ask for registration in Drupal 7?

Tags: users

There is no login block in my website but everyday I see lot's of strange emails are sent they ask for registration. How do I can modify Drupal to reject every registration request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Configure > People > Account Settings (/admin/config/people/accounts) and set it so only Administrators can register accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Drupal to only allow registation by admins? There's a setting where people can register, but administration aproval is needed: I think you have this setting and simply are receiving the notifications to aprove those registrations. Just check the registration only by admin in People settings (admin/config/people/accounts)